# Dynamic or static content generation for rarely-changed data in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, webserver

I have a large-ish (a few hundred entries) table of data to display on a web page in Django. The data can be procedurally generated from a relatively simple Python structure, or it can be hard-coded into the page template, as it should never change once entered (except for formatting and stying down the road, I suppose).

I would rather generate it procedurally from the minimal data structure in Python as this means I can tweak the rendering easily in future, easily modify data in the unlikely event I need to change it, reduce the amount of markup that I would otherwise need to write (DRY and all that...), reduce the chance of breaking the markup and also allow me to abstract the table generation into re-usable methods. However, this also means that the content needs to be generated when requested.

I suspect that caching and the speed of computation on even a fairly basic server is sufficient to make this something that I don't need to worry about, but I'm not sure about the soundness of the general approach, especially if I end up with much more data than I currently have. Is there a "best practice" for this kind of thing, or perhaps some sort of middle road, like generate-at-collectstatic-time, which retains the programmatic generation but also means the server doesn't need to compose the pages on the fly?

Comment: One possible approach would be to abstract the seed data into a file/DB and generate the output on-demand, caching it in some way (memcached/file/DB/whatever). Server than checks if seed data file was modified after last cache generation and rebuilds the cache. Gives you flexibility in choosing caching mechanism, initial data size and structure, plus avoids computationally expensive tasks until actually needed.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching